# Scanf using \n. Don't know what does it do

Tags: c++, c++11, scanf

I am new to programming and I can't figure out what is happening. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   int c,d;
   scanf("%d\n", &c);
   cout<<c<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I can't understand why it's taking two inputs and printing the first one out.

Comment: you dont need `int d` here.  `%d` is a format specifier for scanf

Comment: Srry i was trying some stuff with the another variable d. Just ignore it.

Comment: I see only one input: `"%d\n"` says read an integer (`%d`), and `&c` is where the integer is stored after it is read from the input. Where's the second input?

Comment: A `\n` in the `scanf` format string matches _whitespace_: any whitespace, not just a hit of the Enter key. When **you** hit the Enter key, `stdin`'s line buffer is flushed. The `scanf` then parses the (first) `int`, gobbles up any whitespace after it, stops _before_ the 2nd `int`, returns, then your code prints that first `int` and quits.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist So any whitespace character will flush the line buffer?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist why don't you post this as an answer?

Comment: Thanks for that was really confused about it. @IwillnotexistIdonotexist

Comment: @RaidForce No; `\n` in `scanf`'s _format string_ matches `\n`, `\t`, `\r`, space and anything that counts as whitespace _in the input stream_. But only pressing the Enter key on your keyboard will flush the input line buffer (and allow the line to be seen by `scanf`)

Comment: Why are you using `scanf` in C++ code? Then use `cout` afterwards. Perhaps using `cin` is the order of the day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\n` in a `scanf` format string means to read *any amount of [whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character)*.

So to ensure this action is carried out, it must keep reading until it reads a non-whitespace character.

Another factor at play is that terminal input defaults to being line-buffered; so data is not available for `scanf` to check until you press Enter.

The result of this is that you need to type in your number, plus another non-whitespace character, and press Enter, in order to satisfy `"%d\n"`.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, not mix C-style input/output (`sacnf`, `printf`, etc.) with C++style (`cout`, `cin`, stc.).
Concerning your question, the problem is in the format line for `scanf` function. Change code to:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   int c,d;
   scanf("%d", &c);
   cout<<c<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

and see the difference.

The simplest explanation of why `"%d\n"` require second input is:
`scanf` use `%d` as instruction to find a number in the input stream, and additional `\n` requires to wait for character with code equal to newline code, but `scanf` always stop reading input stream and stop working after reading newline character, so `scanf("%d\n", &c)` needs two newline - the first to satisfy requirement of format line, and the second to be sure that input finished.